# Next-auth Credentials Provider authenticated state doesn't update

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using next-auth 4.18.4 and can't figure out how to set up the Credential provider properly. At this point, when the user logs in, the `status` remains `unauthenticated`, and only updates to `authenticated` when I refresh the page. This is what I have in `api/auth/[...nextauth].ts`:

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { verifyPassword } from '../../../lib/auth'
import conn from '../../../lib/db'

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1`
        const values = [ credentials.username ]
        let user
        try {
          const result = await conn.query(query, values)
          if (result.rows.length > 0) user = result.rows[0]
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(`Error fetching user from DB: ${err.stack}`)
          throw new Error(err)
        }

        if (!user) throw new Error('No user found!')

        const isValid = await verifyPassword(
          credentials?.password,
          user.password
        )

        if (!isValid) throw new Error('Could not log you in!')

        return {
          uid: user.id,
          username: user.username,
          profilePic: user.profile_pic
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```

This is my login page:

```js
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { z } from 'zod'
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import Input from "../components/input"

const validationSchema = z
  .object({
    userName: z
      .string()
      .min(1, { message: 'Username is required' })
      .regex(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{5,10}$/, {
        message: '5-10 upper and lowercase letters, and digits',
      }),
    password: z
      .string()
      .min(5, { message: 'Between 5-10 characters' })
      .regex(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{5,10}$/, {
        message: 'Upper and lowercase letters, and digits',
      })
  })

export default function Auth() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
    setValue
  } = useForm({
    mode: 'all',
    resolver: zodResolver(validationSchema),
  })
  const router = useRouter()

  async function submitHandler(data: any) {
    const result = await signIn('credentials', {
      redirect: false, // don't redirect if user enters wrong credentials
      username: data.userName,
      password: data.password
    })
    // console.log(result) // testing

    // If the 'error' property is null (meaning log in was successful)
    if (!result?.error) {
      // Let's clear the input fields
      setValue('userName', '')
      setValue('password', '')
      // And redirect the user to the main page
      router.replace('/')
    } else {
      // If the 'error' property was false, let's print the login error
      console.log(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(result.error)}`)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='text-white max-w-4xl mx-auto pt-10 pb-20 px-2'>
      <h1 className='text-2xl text-center pb-8'>Log in</h1>

      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitHandler)}
        className='space-y-4 flex flex-col items-center '
      >
        <Input
          id='userName'
          type='text'
          label='Username'
          register={register}
          registerOptions={{ required: true }}
          errors={errors}
          isRequired={true}
        />

        <Input
          id='password'
          type='password'
          label='Password'
          register={register}
          registerOptions={{ required: true }}
          errors={errors}
          isRequired={true}
        />

        <button
          type='submit'
          disabled={!isValid}
          className={`p-3 border-[1px] border-slate-500 rounded-md hover:enabled:bg-white hover:enabled:bg-opacity-20 disabled:cursor-not-allowed w-[90%]`}
        >
          {isValid ? 'Log In' : 'Please, fill the form'}
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And my `index` page:

```js
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'

export default function Home() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()
  console.log(status);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className='text-2xl text-white text-center p-4'>Home Page</h1>
      {status === 'authenticated' ?
      (<h2 className='text-2xl text-white p-14'>Logged in!</h2>)
      :
      (<h2 className='text-2xl text-white p-14'>Not logged in!</h2>)
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

And the session provider in `_app.ts`:

```js
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react'

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

By the way, I forgot to add that after logging in, I can see the `next-auth.session` cookie being created in the browser, but still, status doesn't change until I reload.

Comment: Have you added the `SessionProvider` to your `_app.js` file? https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#sessionprovider

Comment: @braza oh yes, forgot to add that code. I'll edit the question.